# z-index and css the definitive guide figure 10-55

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm reading chapter 10 of "CSS the Definitive Guide" 3rd Edition and there is a code example for figure 10-55 that I can't reproduce and I don't know what's wrong.

Specifically the code in the book says

```
p {border: 1px solid; background: #DDD; margin: 0;}
b {background: #808080;}
em {background: #BBB;}
#one {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; height: 10em; z-index: 10;}
#two {position: absolute; top: 5em; left: 25%; width: 50%; height: 10em; z-index: 7;}
#three {position: absolute; top: 11em; left: 0; width: 50%; height: 10em; z-index: 1;}
#one b {position: absolute; right: -3em; top: auto; z-index: 36;}
#two em {position: absolute; bottom: -0.75em; left: 7em; right: -2em; z-index: -42;}
#three b {position: absolute; left: 3em; top: 3.5em; width: 25em; z-index:23;}
```

and Figure 10-55 looks like this:

[image: Figure 10-55]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dunsondog109/WvJxR/

However,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
        border: 1px solid;
        background: #DDD;
        margin: 0;
      }
      b {
        background: #808080;
      }
      em {
        background: #BBB;
      }
      #one {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10em;
        z-index: 10;
      }
      #two {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5em;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10em;
        z-index: 7;
      }
      #three {
        position: absolute;
        top: 11em;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10em;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      #one b {
        position: absolute;
        right: -5em;
        top: 4em;
        width: 20em;
        z-index: -404;
      }
      #two b {
        position: absolute;
        right: -3em;
        top: auto;
        z-index: 36;
      }
      #two em {
        position absolute;
        bottom: -0.75em;
        left: 7em;
        right: -2em;
        z-index: -42;
      }
      #three b {
        position: absolute;
        left: 3em;
        top: 3.5em;
        width: 25em;
        z-index: 23;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="one">
      This element contains normal text with in the browser. There is also some <em>[one]emphasized</em> text to place, or not, depending on the element in question. This element is ID'd "one," if that helps.<b>[one] a boldfaced element big enough to see</b>
    </p>
    <p id="two">
  This element contains normal text with in the browser. There is also some <em>[one]emphasized</em> text to place, or not, depending on the element in question. This element is ID'd "two," if that helps.<b>[two] a boldfaced element big enough to see</b>
    </p>
    <p id="three">
  This element contains normal text with in the browser. There is also some <em>[one]emphasized</em> text to place, or not, depending on the element in question. This element is ID'd "three," if that helps.<b>[three] a boldfaced element big enough to see</b>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

produces

[image]

My question is:

Why is the bold element showing up in front of it's parent when it's z-index is lower? Furthermore, how do I correct my code to make it look like the picture in the book?

Comment: Z-index is always relative to its parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I Suspect a Book Error (because of a Browser Error)

Here's what I suspect. The *CSS the Definitive Guide* 3rd ed. was printed 2006. [This website from 2008](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/) mentions that Firefox gets the rendering of the negative `z-index` *incorrect* (though personally, I think the Firefox version is what it should be and the spec should change; but that's my opinion). The difference in the rendering of IE vs. Firefox in that article is the difference that you are seeing now (and also, FF no longer renders it the way it used to, but the "correct" way). So it is quite likely that the image used for the book was from Firefox and rendered "incorrectly" at that time.

Therefore, to "properly" get it to *now* render similar to the book image, the topmost element (`#one`) cannot be given its own `z-index` other than `auto` (which is the default if no `z-index` is set, and essentially equivalent to `0`) as anything else will establish a new stacking context, and its child elements will not go "behind" the other elements.

[**So this fiddle uses the following `z-index` settings**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvJxR/9/) to keep the stacking context of the `#one` children *equal* to the stacking context of `#two` and `#three` while also pushing those div elements below `#one` (which gives the same effect as the book):

```css
#one     { /* none = z-index: auto; prevents new stacking context */ }
#two     { z-index:  -2;} /* we want it below both #one and its child <b> */
#three   { z-index:  -3;} /* we want it below #two */
#one b   { z-index:  -1;} /* push behind #one but stay in front of #two, etc. */
#two b   { z-index:  36;} /* this and all the rest are "irrelevant" to #one */
#two em  { z-index: -42;}
#three b { z-index:  23;}
```

[Stacking contexts (note that besides `position`, `opacity` below `1` creates a new stacking context also) are complicated things at times](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context), affecting the [`z-index` rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index), and sometimes making one's head spin as to why something isn't where you expect it. When you throw in rendering issues for various older browsers (and it was surprising to find FF in "error" here), that just adds to the confusion.

Hopefully this helps explain what may be happening with you and why you cannot get it to render correctly.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for this thorough explanation. Yeah it seems like expected behavior of z-index can be unintuitive sometimes. Furthermore, expected behavior on specific browsers even more so.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/WvJxR/5/

You have to give a relative position to the div to hide.

Something like that:

```
 #one b {
    position: relative;
    right: -5em;
    top: 4em;
    width: 20em;
    z-index: -404;
 }
```

Comment: It's still in front of the paragraph. I'm using the latest version of Safari.